# How to pass the updated current_number into the exiting variable

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a generator for naming conventions for several applications. The idea is that the user can choose what application type and application name should be append to the generated name. This functions fine.

Where my code doesn't seems to work is when I'm trying to iterate the passed unique number `current_number` and to set the iterated number as the new current_number. So when "249" generated the next number which should be generated is "250", etc. This is the current state:

```
class namegenerator():
def __init__(self, applicationtype, applicationname):
    self.applicationtype = applicationtype
    self.applicationname = applicationname



def numbergen(self):

    current_number = 248

    while current_number < current_number + 1:
        current_number +=1 

    return self.applicationtype + "_" + self.applicationname + "_" + "0" + str(current_number)
            break
```

I would expect that the value from the variable `current_number` is updated by + 1 for every time a new name is generated. Instead all the created names get the same updated value instead of an iterated one.

Example Name #1:

```
    n = namegenerator("SD", "DMORCP01")
    n.numbergen()
```

Output:`'SD_DMORCP01_0249'`

Example Name #2:

```
    n = namegenerator("VD","DMFIAP01")
    n.numbergen()
```

Output: `'VD_DMFIAP01_0249'`

But actually i would expect for Name #2 the number to be "250".

Expected output for Name #2: `'VD_DMFIAP01_0250'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring a new variable **current_number** with initial value 248 within **numbergen()** method , therefor each time you call method it will declare this variable again and again with the same value incremented by 1 and you will get the same result.

Solution is to add **current_number** as an instance attribute into object constructor method **__init__**, because instance attribute is declared at instance creation and belongs to only one object so stored value will not be overridden when you call method.

Also if you want to increment variable only by 1, you don't need to create while loop just use **+=** operator.

Solution:

```
class namegenerator():
    def __init__(self, applicationtype, applicationname):
        self.applicationtype = applicationtype
        self.applicationname = applicationname
        self.current_number = 248

    def numbergen(self):
        self.current_number += 1
        return self.applicationtype + "_" + self.applicationname + "_" + "0" + str(self.current_number)
```

Example:

```
a = namegenerator('TYPE1', 'APPNAME')
b = namegenerator('TYPE2', 'APPNAME')
print a.numbergen()
print b.numbergen()
```

In this example is current_number bound to instance (each instance has own current_number counter)

Output:

TYPE1_APPNAME_0249

TYPE2_APPNAME_0249

If you need to have shared value among objects of same type you can declare class attribute of **namegenerator**

```
class namegenerator():
    current_number = 248

    def __init__(self, applicationtype, applicationname):
        self.applicationtype = applicationtype
        self.applicationname = applicationname

    def numbergen(self):
        namegenerator.current_number += 1
        return self.applicationtype + "_" + self.applicationname + "_" + "0" + str(namegenerator.current_number)
```

The same example OUTPUT:

TYPE1_APPNAME_0249

TYPE2_APPNAME_0250

Comment: Thats it. The declaration of the class attribute was the key. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite while loop: `current_number < current_number + 1` is always true, so the code shouldn't actually get out of that loop. If you just want to increase `current_number` by one each time you should just keep the `current_number += 1` and store the `current_number` variable somewhere. I have no experience with python class creation so I can't help you there.